# Listen to a variable, if changes trigger some code

Tags: android, listener

I'm want to check running apps by using `ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo` and if `com.example.myapp` package contains in list start some service:

```
List<String> lst = new ArrayList<String>();

ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
         List<RunningTaskInfo> recentTasks = activityManager
                .getRunningTasks(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

         for(RunningTaskInfo item : recentTasks){

             lst.add(item.baseActivity.getPackageName());
         }
```

My problem is how i can listen to `lst List<String>` and after this `List<String>` changes call some methods or start some service.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create your own implementation of list and override each method. Your class can inherit of ArrayList for example. In each method which modify the list, you call your listener:

```
public voolean add(T value) {
   if(super.add(value)) {
        callListeners()
   }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but there is no another way to get notify when it's contents changes??

Comment: Well no. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16468612/4874829) answer for a fully written class.

Comment: @ Yoav Sternberg  : Thanks for your answer but it's complex topic for me. I solve my problem with another solution.